# Cant fetch more items from a user

Tags: laravel, graphql

I am making a laravel project where users can be seperated to 2 things, brand and supplier. As Supplier you can have products.

The problem is that as Supplier i can only fetch 1 product with ->first(), i found out that i have to do ->get(), but it will give me a error.

->first()
[first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cu2aL.png)
response =
[response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCwtQ.png)

->get()
[get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUwE4.png)
response =
[response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6YVX.png)

Did i missed something?

thx in advance

Comment: I don't know if this is related to the error, but be aware that when you use `first()`, it returns an object. But, when you use `get()`, it returns a Collection. So you have to iterate over it to get the products.

Comment: Hey, Please take a picture of all the code, that we could see it all. I think the problem is the response that you are trying to send.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `first()` on a model will run the query and return the first result as an instance of whatever Model class it was called on. `get()` runs the query and returns and instance of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`, which you can think of as an array of model objects.

Basically it means if you use `get()` instead of `first()` you have to change your code to expect a Collection (array) back. Depending what your code does, that might mean adding a loop.

More on the Laravel docs: [Retrieving models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#retrieving-models), [Eloquent Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-collections#introduction)

Answer (score 0):

try adding nullable() to your `product id` column in your migration. sample:

```
$table->integer('id')->nullable()
```

then run the following in your command line,

```
1.composer dump-autoload // updates the changes in your migration

2.php artisan migrate:fresh --seed //new migration and seeds your seeders
```